# How to find out if user has previous login credentials before signing in with google firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am creating my login page on my webapp and on it I have successfully implemented the google signup button. It is working fine for new users but when existing users are supposed to log in it is supposed to throw an error of 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential' which is not being thrown, as a result the previous user data of email and password is being completely overwritten with new auth of google instead of being merged together. Here's my code snippet, any help will be appreciated

```js
const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const signinGoogle = () => {
  auth
    .signInWithPopup(googleProvider)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.user);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        var pendingCred = error.credential;
        var email = error.email;
        auth.fetchProvidersForEmail(email).then(function (methods) {
          if (methods[0] === 'password') {
            var password = prompt('Enter your password');
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (result) {
              return result.user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
};
```

I have done everything according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-1 but the main problem is the error is not thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs from your link say:

> A user logging in with Google will never cause this error when their account is hosted at Google even if they signed up for their account with a password or a social IDP.

That means if someone registered with email and password and later on signs in with Google it will overrride the previous data. The password get lost.

You could use `firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` to check what providers the email used and redirect to that one but it would not make a nice `UX` for those who already use Google Signin. Because they would need to enter the email manually just to go to the proper signin method.

If the user is on the same device you could store the last signin method somewhere in the local storage and use that to route the user to the right direction.

Unfortunately there is no strict and nice solution for this behaviour.